# How do I constrain a member of a parameter class to match the instance of an outer class?

Tags: scala

The following code does not compile, because the compiler cannot prove that `v.o.Inner` and `Outer.this.Inner` are the same, in the implementation of `visit()`. I cannot see how to tell the compiler than `v.o` must be `Outer.this` such that its recognized at compiler time. Any ideas?

```
class Outer {
   class Inner {
      def visit(v:Visitor) = v.visitInner(this)
   }
}

class Visitor(val o:Outer) {
    def visitInner(i:o.Inner) = { println("foo") } 
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler cannot prove that because that is false. For example:

```
val o1 = new Outer
val o2 = new Outer
val o2i = new o2.Inner
val v = new Visitor(o1)

o2i.visit(v)
```

Here the `Outer` of `v` is `o1`, but the `Outer` of `this` (`o2i`) is `o2`.

If what you are asking is how to enforce the types so that it becomes so, this might help:

```
class Outer {
   self => 
   class Inner {
      def visit(v:Visitor[self.type]) = v.visitInner(this)
   }
}

class Visitor[T <: Outer](val o:T) {
    def visitInner(i:o.Inner) = { println("foo") } 
}
```

However, type inference won't help you if you go this route. You'll have to be explicit about the type of any `Visitor`, like this:

```
val v = new Visitor[o1.type](o1)
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew it had to be something to do with self-types, but did not realize you needed the additional template parameter. Obvious now you show it.